# + exportSessionWithAsset:presetName: returning nil on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios7, avmutablecomposition

I'm using the following code:

```
- (AVAssetExportSession *)testRecording
{
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:kTestSongName withExtension:@"mp3"];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(0, 600), asset.duration);
    NSError *editError;

    BOOL result = [composition insertTimeRange:range ofAsset:asset atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&editError];
    if (!result) {
        NSLog(@"Error inserting timerange");
    }
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession
                                           exportSessionWithAsset:composition
                                           presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    return exportSession;

}
```

This does what it's supposed to on iOS8 but on iOS7 exportSession is always nil at the end of the method. I tried using assets with different formats (mp3, caf) but the result was the same.

If I play the composition instead of exporting it the sound is fine:

```
AVPlayerItem * item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:composition];
AVPlayer * player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
[player play];
```

Any idea about what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                                              initWithAsset:songAsset
                                              presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
        exportSession.outputFileType = @"com.apple.m4a-audio";
    filePath = [[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"m4a.mov"]
        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
                NSString *newPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentDirectory, [[[filePath lastPathComponent] substringToIndex:[[filePath lastPathComponent] length]-5] stringByAppendingString:@"a"]];
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:newPath error:nil];
                NSError *error = nil;
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:filePath toPath:newPath error:&error];
            }
            if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled) {
            }
            if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting) {
            }
            if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed) {
                          NSLog(@"erros:%@",exportSession.error);
            }
            if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown) {
            }
            if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting) {
            }
        }];
```

If you want to save in mp3 format, use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/index.html).